# A problem with assertRaises function in Python

Tags: python, assertraises

I am trying to run the following test

```
 self.assertRaises(Exception,lambda:
 unit_test.testBasic())
```

where

```
test.testBasic()
```

is

```
class IsPrimeTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def assertRaises(self,exception,callable,*args,**kwargs):
        print('dfdf')
        temp = callable
        super().assertRaises(exception,temp,*args,**kwargs)

   def testBasic_helper(self):

        self.failIf(is_prime(2))
        self.assertTrue(is_prime(1))
```

where prime is a function,and

but in

```
self.assertRaises(Exception,lambda:
unit_test.testBasic())
```

the lambda function doesnt throws an exception after 
the test

```
def testBasic_helper(self):

   self.failIf(is_prime(2))
   self.assertTrue(is_prime(1))
```

fails
Can somebody offers a solution to the problem?

---

I'll try to explain my problem ,again ,because in my first post i didn't explain it very well
So here is the source 
is_prime(x) is just a function for checking for prime numbers

def is_prime(number):
    PRIME, NOT_PRIME = not is_prime.broken, is_prime.broken
    if number == 2:
        return PRIME

```
if not isinstance(number, int) and not isinstance(number, float):
    raise Exception

if number % 2 == 0 or number < 2 or isinstance(number, float):
    return NOT_PRIME

max = int(number**0.5) + 1
for i in range(3, max, 2):
    if number % i == 0:
        return NOT_PRIME
return PRIME
```

is_prime.broken = False

> class IsPrimeTest(unittest.TestCase):
>
> ```
> def testBasic_helper(self):
>
>           self.failIf(is_prime(1))
>           self.assertTrue(is_prime(2))
>           self.failIf(is_prime(4))
>           self.failIf(is_prime(6))
>           self.assertTrue(is_prime(7))
>
>
> def testBasic(self):
>     return self.testBasic_helper()
>
> def testNegative(self):
>     self.failIf(is_prime(-2))
>     self.failIf(is_prime(-11 ** 3))
>
> def testNonNumber(self):
>     self.assertRaises(Exception,is_prime,'asd')
>     self.assertRaises(Exception,is_prime,self.__class__.__name__)
>
> def testRandom(self):
>
>     for i in range(0,10000):
>         rand = randint(-10000,10000)
>         self.assertEquals(prime(rand),is_prime(rand))
> ```

and here is Test,we can say that the test tests the program which is a test - a test over test

class MetaProgrammingTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_decorator(self):
        from p10 import unit_converter

```
    def celsius_function(val):
        return val

    self.assertTrue(hasattr(unit_converter(1,2),'__call__'))
    decorated = unit_converter(1.8, 32)(celsius_function)
    self.assertTrue(hasattr(decorated, '__call__'))
    self.assertAlmostEquals(64.4, decorated(val = 18.0))


def test_unit_test(self):
    import p10
    from p10sample import is_prime as is_prime_actual

    unit_test = p10.IsPrimeTest('testBasic')
    unit_test.setUp()

    is_prime_actual.broken = False

    self.assertEquals(None, unit_test.testBasic())
    self.assertEquals(None, unit_test.testNegative())
    self.assertEquals(None, unit_test.testNonNumber())
    self.assertEquals(None, unit_test.testRandom())

    is_prime_actual.broken = True

    self.assertRaises(Exception,lambda: unit_test.testBasic())
    self.assertRaises(Exception, lambda: unit_test.testNegative())
    self.assertRaises(Exception, lambda: unit_test.testRandom())

    unit_test.tearDown()
```

I,cant change the second test - the test over the test
So the expression self.assertRaises(Exception,lambda: unit_test.testBasic()) 
has to stay unchaged
My problem is that when testBasic() function fails ,for example if we have 
self.assertFailIf(is_prime(2)) ,self.assertfailIf throws an exception,unit_test.testBasic()
throws the same exception to the upper scope,but lambda:unit_test.testBasic() doesnt throws the exception and 
the check 
self.assertRaises(Exception,lambda: unit_test.testBasic())
fails 
My question is how to make the  testBasic() function  so that lambda: unit_test.testBasic() will  thorw the exceotion and selfassertRaises won't fail,any ideas??

Comment: Code is formatted just by intend the lines with four spaces, not appending a `>`. That is a quote.

Answer (score 1):

Do I understand you correctly in that you're asking why the testBasic_helper method doesn't raise an exception when the test runs?
I don't see why it should, the is_prime should return a bool value against which the test checks for failure. If the test fails, it simply fails, neither your code nor the unittest framework throws in exception.

P.S. "unit_test.testBasic" is already a callable, the "lambda: unit_test.testBasic()" is superfluous, so you can just write self.assertRaises(Exception, unit_test.testBasic).

Comment: What does "superfleous" mean??

Comment: That's a typo, correctly spelled it's "superfluous", meaning it's not needed.